# Autohotkey for letter a + Enter key

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to know the script for replacing my <kbd>Insert</kbd> Key with the letter <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

So if I press <kbd>Insert</kbd>, letter a should be typed and then the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just to ensure this answer is understood. It is for Autohotkey and when you run this the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key changes its behaviour into pressing the <kbd>a</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
Ins::
    Send, a{Enter}
Return
```

Comment: This isn't very useful how it @alisha suppose to know what language this is or what to do with it. ADD A DESCRIPTION!!!

Comment: Obviously it is a autohotkey script sending a and enter when insert is pressed. Some words wouldn't hurt, anyway.

Comment: @JensErat The asker may not know this.

Comment: He asked explicitly for one.